# How to make div height 100% inside relative div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"> CHILDREN 1 </div>
  <div class="child-2"> CHILDREN 2 </div>
  <div class="child-3"> CHILDREN 3 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}
.child-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.child-2 {
  height: 100%;
}
.child-3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I set child-2 as **100%** but didn't happen. So, how to make **.child-2** height 100% and between child-1 and child-3?

Comment: Sorry I didn't completely understand what you meant.  Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/bfp84upn/

Comment: Do you want `.child-2` to be height 100% *minus* the heights of `child-1` and `child-3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly what you want to do... This seems like a job for Captain FlexBox®.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: Yellow;
}
.child-1 {
  background: Red;
}
.child-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  background: Green;
}
.child-3 {
  background: Blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"> CHILDREN 1 </div>
  <div class="child-2"> CHILDREN 2 </div>
  <div class="child-3"> CHILDREN 3 </div>
</div>
```

The important parts are setting `display: flex` on the container, instructing the rendering engine to calculate by the `flex` rules, changing the direction to vertical with `flex-direction: column` and making only the middle child fill up all the remaining space with `flex-grow: 1`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you delete the `position: absolute;` from your .child you will get that you want, cause in your case you get the .child-2 on the top of .child-1 div.

Try this:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}
.child-1 {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.child-2 {
  height: 100%;
}
.child-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **display:table-cell** property for this

Comment: Add example please

Comment: Yes, example necessary, I'm trying to do this and it isn't working.  I've set height to 100% and using table on the parent and it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Add your child-2 below css:

```
.child-2 {
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
}
```

And your child-3 class top 100%:

```
.child-3 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
top: 100%;
}
```

child-2 will become at the middle of the other two divs.